# Own calc in windows command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I wrote a code to calculate some expressions. It works like this:`calc 5+  6 + 8*7` must output 67.
The problem that I faced is bitwise operators:`calc 1 ^& 0` gives error. Idea of my calc is simple. First stick all our input together in `set a` and then `set /A a=%a%` to calculate the expression
My code:

```
@echo off
if "%1" == "" goto :help
if "%1" == "/?" goto :help

set "g="

:start
rem ***Stick all our input together*** 
set "g=%g%%1"
if not "%1" == "" (
if "%1" == "/?" (
    goto :help
    )
shift
goto :start 
)

echo %g%| findstr /R "[^0123456789\+\-\*\/\(\)] \+\+ \-\- \*\* \/\/ \= \=\= \^^"  >nul 2>&1
if not ERRORLEVEL 1 goto error

set /A "g=%g%" 2>nul
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto error

echo %g%
set g=
goto :EOF

:help
echo This is simple calculator
echo Usage: Mycalc.cmd [/?] (EXPRESSION)
echo Available operands:+,-,*,/,(,)
goto :EOF

:error
echo Wrong input or calculation error.
```

I think that the problem when we enter `calc 1 ^& 0` there is error to `echo %g%`: `0 is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: what's the problem with `set /a %*` ?

Comment: To catch some calculation errors and replace them with ours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the & character. You can force the command line to accept & as a valid character as you are doing it, with ^ prefix, but once it is in a variable, each time you use this variable in the batch file you get a real ampersand.

In your example, calling calc 1 ^& 0 , when executing

```
echo %g%
```

what the cmd file is running is

```
echo 1 & 0
```

echo the character 1 and run program 0

How to solve?

```
rem read all command line and put inside quotes
    set a="%*"

rem replace ampersand with escaped ampersand
    set a=%a:&=^&%

rem execute calculation without quotes
    set /a a=%a:"=%
```

And, of course, call cmd with escaped ampersand

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the output of `&` or `|` as MC ND and aphoria mentioned.
To solve it use at best delayed expansion, as this doesn't care about these characters.

This can handle `calc 1^&3` or also calc "1&3"

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "param=%~1"
echo !param!
```

But you got extra problems as you try to pipe this to findstr, this needs extra handling

Answer (score 1):

Your original code needed some fixes and code simplifications, here is a working version:

```
@echo off

if "%~1" EQU ""   (goto :help)
if "%~1" EQU "/?" (goto :help)

:start
rem ***Stick all our input together*** 
Set "g=%*"
set /A "g=%g: =%"
REM echo Input: "%g%"

set /A "g=%g%" 2>nul || (goto error)

echo %g%
set "g="
goto :EOF

:help
echo This is simple calculator
echo Usage: Mycalc.cmd [/?] (EXPRESSION)
echo Available operands:+,-,*,/,(,)
goto :EOF

:error
echo Wrong input or calculation error.
```

PS: Try it as normally without passing additional (I mean double or triple) `^` characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use three `^` to escape it, like this:

```
calc 1 ^^^& 0
```

Comment: I also have same error `echo %g%`: `0 is not recognized as an internal or external command` when I type `calc 1 ^^^& 0` I think the problem is that I do `echo %g%` not just once.

Answer (score 0):

#### Here is an example without `DelayedExpansion` or `goto` statements.

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "Input=%*"
rem No Input, display help
if not defined Input ( call :Help ) else call :Main || call :Error
endlocal & exit /b %ErrorLevel%

:Main
rem Clean Input of poison double quotations
set "Input=%Input:"=%"
rem Check for the /? help parameter
if "/?"=="%Input:~0,2%" call :Help & exit /b 0
rem Validate the characters in the Input
for /f "delims=0123456789+-*/()&|    " %%A in ("%Input%") do exit /b 1
rem Perform the calculations
set /a "Input=%Input: =%" 2>nul
rem Validate the Result
for /f "delims=0123456789" %%A in ("%Input%") do exit /b 1
rem Display the Result
echo(%Input%
exit /b %ErrorLevel%

:Help
echo This is simple calculator
echo Usage: Mycalc.cmd [/?] (EXPRESSION)
echo Available operands:+,-,*,/,^(,^),^&,^|
exit /b 0

:Error
echo Wrong input or calculation error.
exit /b 0
```